# Webdriver in Ruby, how to make coke reusable by making classes

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple webdriver test in ruby below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
# example application under test
driver.get "https://dev08-olb.nz.thenational.com/ib4b/app/login"

element = driver.find_element :id => "accessId"
element.send_keys "123456"

element = driver.find_element :id => "userId"
element.send_keys "user1"

element = driver.find_element :id => "password"
element.send_keys "password1"
element.submit

if 
 "Hello".eql? driver.title
  puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
else 
 puts "damn it, it must be Monday"
end

driver.quit
```

In the future there will be lots of other cases require log in so we want to repeat as less as possible so we create the following two ruby scripts.

**LogIn.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class LogIn
    def initialize(accessID, user, pass)
    @accessID    = accessID
    @user   = user
    @pass = pass

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.get "https://dev08-olb.nz.thenational.com/ib4b/app/login"

    element = driver.find_element :id => "accessId"
    element.send_keys @accessID

    element = driver.find_element :id => "userId"
    element.send_keys @user

    element = driver.find_element :id => "password"
    element.send_keys @pass
    element.submit
  end
end
```

**HelloWorld.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require './LogIn'

LogIn.new("123456","user1","password1")

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
 if 
 "Hello".eql? driver.title
  puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
else 
 puts "damn it, it must be Monday"
end

driver.quit
```

However in HelloWorld.rb driver gets instantiated twice so two instance of the browser gets open at test execution, which is not desired. But if I don't instantiate driver in HelloWorld.rb, I can't access its property later.

What's your way of managing these kind of situation?

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more about how to program tests in Ruby, rather than Selenium specific. There are many ways of doing it.

Here is one, try initialize `driver` `HelloWorld.rb`, then pass it into `Login.rb`

**HelloWorld.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require './LogIn'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

LogIn.new(driver, "123456","user1","password1")

 if 
 "Hello".eql? driver.title
  puts "Page title is #{driver.title}"
else 
 puts "damn it, it must be Monday"
end

driver.quit
```

**Login.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class LogIn
    def initialize(driver, accessID, user, pass)
    @driver = driver
    @accessID    = accessID
    @user   = user
    @pass = pass

    driver.get "https://dev08-olb.nz.thenational.com/ib4b/app/login"

    element = driver.find_element :id => "accessId"
    element.send_keys @accessID

    element = driver.find_element :id => "userId"
    element.send_keys @user

    element = driver.find_element :id => "password"
    element.send_keys @pass
    element.submit
  end
end
```